# NSURLSessionDownloadTask API call clarification on syntax in Swift

Tags: ios, api, swift, concurrency, nsurl

I'm learning to do a basic networking call, and following a tutorial. The tutorial goes through concurrency, and downloading the JSON data in the background thread. I was wondering why in the sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL method the queryURL would be passed as the NSURL object as opposed to the baseURL. I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious!

```
func searchRecipeData() {

    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.recipes.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=\(apiID)&_app_key=\(apiKey)")
    let queryURL = NSURL(string: "&q=onion+soup", relativeToURL: baseURL)!

    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let downloadData: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(queryURL, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseURL!)

            println(data)

        }
    })
    // Resumes it even though it hasn't started yet
    downloadData.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the second parameter where you create queryURL.  You are passing the baseURL constant.  What happens is that the '&q=onion+soup' query parameter is told to be relative to the baseURL.  The queryURL constant is the full URL, and it is then passed to downloadTaskWithURL.